Batch sleep with interrupt?
I had a sleep loop at first that used timeout /t 300 but then I needed simple interop, like being able to restart the script without waiting ~2.5 minutes.
My only attempted solution is to run timeout /t 1 300 times. Since timeout is a process, this obviously creates quite the issue; nobody wants to spawn a process every second, even if it's just a small cmd line tool.
Do I have to rewrite the script in powershell or is this possible to solve with batch?
